# Library Installation order in automake

Tags: automake

When I am running make distcheck, one library (lib2 in this example) is not being installed because it requires lib1.

Is there any way to mandate the order of library installation?

Makefile.am:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libTwo.la libOne.la

libOne_la_SOURCES = lib/one/example.cpp \
    lib/one/example.h 

libTwo_la_SOURCES = lib/two/Example2.cpp \
    lib/two/Example2.h 

libTwo_la_CPPFLAGS = -I$(srcdir)/lib/one
libTwo_la_LIBADD = libOne.la
```

I am using:

- RedHatEnterpriseServer 5.5
- automake (GNU automake) 1.9.6

*Edit: * Here is what I am seeing on the make distcheck output.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOne
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
libtool: install: error: relink `libTwo.la' with the above command before installing it
/bin/sh ./libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c  'libOne.la' '/tmp/xx-x-yy-21346    /home/foo/commonlib-1.0/_inst/lib/libOne.la'
```

Comment: Where is `lib1.la` in your Makefile? I don't see it.  All I see is stuff for `libOne.la` and `libTwo.la`.  Also you'll need to post what goes into `lib_LTLIBRARIES` or whatever you using to install.

Comment: Thanks @ldav1s. I have edited accordingly, let me know if I'm still not making sense.

Comment: I'm kind of assuming `-lone` is really `-lOne` in the `make distcheck` output.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, I edited the question to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try exchanging:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libTwo.la libOne.la
```

for:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libOne.la libTwo.la
```

IIRC, the order in `lib_LTLIBRARIES` matters at install time.